# Mysql : Query to update email with unique random value

Tags: mysql

I need to anonymize emails in DB, so I try to set a query, but I cannot find a way to generate unique random string for each. 
What I have so far is :

```
update candidate set email = (select CONCAT(SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 15) , '@test.fr'));
```

But obviously the value is not unique, is that possible with a simple query?

I tried solution here : https://harrybailey.com/2015/08/mysql-roughly-random-string-generation-for-updating-rows/ but same result, I got a

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0417da5fb3d071b9bd10' for key
>   'email'

Comment: well the solution in that link does say "Be sure to then check for duplicates, which are possible!" so it's not unexpected.

Comment: Anyway it depends how random you need it to be (or whether the values just need to be different from each other), but here's a suggestion: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203697

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use  [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

```
 UPDATE `candidate` SET email = CONCAT(MD5(UUID()),'@test.fr');
```

and if you want exactly 15 characters

```
 UPDATE candidate SET email=CONCAT(SUBSTRING(MD5(UUID()),1,15) , '@test.fr');
```